# Implement an algorithm to find the kth to last element of a singly linked list

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

Implement an algorithm to find the kth to last element of a singly linked list.

Is a good solution to the above problem, reversing the linked list then traversing again and getting the kth element?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the list is `singly-linked`. So that is a good hint that you should not try to reverse it, because you would need as much storage to make the copy.

You can use a modified version of the turtle-hare algorithm:

- Use a `hare` pointer at the start of the list
- Move it at least `K` elements away
- If you hit the `last` element before, then you cannot find the `Kth` to last element.
- Place a `turtle` pointer at the start of the list
- Now runs the `hare` pointer to the end of the list, each time you move the `hare` pointer, moves the `turtle`.

When the `hare` pointer reach the end of the list, the `turtle` is on the `Kth` to last element.