# get third last node from link list using single pass

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

**I have singly link list say,**
10 => 16 => 9 => 6 => 4 => 11 => 18 => **17** => 7 => 8

I don't have given (N) i.e number  of nodes.

**I want to get third last element from above link list with use of single pass.
I want  C code for this. please help me.**

Comment: Keep track of how many items are in the list as you build it.

Comment: You can get ideas for the algorithm here. not the code.

Comment: One more thing. I did not given number of nodes. then ?

Comment: Too bad, it can't be done. Those who say it can be done are only fooling themselves.

Comment: @user3386109, even though we didn't given we can find N using one loop.

Comment: It is a singly linked list, so you can't go back via the nodes. Keep an array of three nodes, initlally all null. update the array with every step along the list so that the nodes in the array are the third but last, second but last and last nodes. Return the third but last node, which wll be null if the list has fewer than three nodes. Alternatively, you can try to have some fun with recursion.

Comment: @AbhishekNehe Yes, that's one pass, and then...?

Comment: yeah got it ... thank you so much....

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507486/implement-an-algorithm-to-find-the-kth-to-last-element-of-a-singly-linked-list#comment52874011_32507486

Answer (score 4):

Since the op already "got it", note that just a single pointer to node could be used:

```
node *thirdtolast(node * list){
    node *pnode = list;
    if(pnode == NULL || pnode->next == NULL || pnode->next->next == NULL)
        return pnode;
    while(pnode->next->next->next != NULL)
        pnode = pnode->next;
    return pnode;
}
```

Using two pointers would be more generic and more efficient:

```
node *thirdtolast(node * list){
    node *pend = list;
    node *pnode = list;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if(pend == NULL)
            return list;
        pend = pend->next;
    }
    while(pend != NULL){
        pend  = pend->next;
        pnode = pnode->next;
    }
    return pnode;
}
```